# Collar Option K Term

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

I know that the value of a collar option on a stock (buy stock, buy put at $K_1$ and sell call at $K_2$) is given by

$$Collar\ Value = K_1d(t,T)+Put\ Value-Call\ Value$$

My question is, why do we have the $K_1$ term and why do we need to discount it?

Answer (score 3):

The collar strategy combines one unit of stock with a (long) put option with strike $K_1$ and a (short) call option with strike $K_2$. The payoff of this strategy is exactly $K_1$ if $S_T\leq K_1$, $S_T$ if $K_1<S_T\leq K_2$ and $K_2$ if $S_T>K_2$. The easiest way to see that the statement is false is by comparing the payoff profiles of the collar and that of your statement. Below $K_1$, the payoff is correct $(K_1)$, but for $S_T>K_1$, the payoff diverges.

---

Start again from the Collar present value
$$
Collar=S+P(K_1)-C(K_2)
$$
and make use of the Put-Call-Parity,  $S+P=C+K$ to arrive at

$$
Collar=\mathbf{C(K_1)}+K_1D(t,T)-C(K_2)
$$

Please note the **emphasis**. The payoff profile of a collar is thus achieved by buying / selling **calls** and entering a bond position with face value $K_1$.

HTH?

Comment: this is old but I'm wondering why just discount K1?

Comment: That’s due to PCP. Only one bond needs to be put out.

Comment: At expiry an option pays out  if >,  if < and  otherwise, where < and  is the underlying. will this be the same ? @kermittfrog

Comment: do you know in which book i can find more details about this please?

Comment: You could give **Hull Options, Futures, and other Derivatives** a go for this.